# Docker Xdebug LAN / Public Dev server

Tags: linux, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I want to get Xdebug running in a semi secure manner over LAN in the office. Our current setup is as follows:

Local server on LAN network under 192.168.1.1 with Ubuntu Server 16

Multiple instances of docker with PHP / Apache running on Ubuntu server

Jwilder nginx proxy for forwarding all requests to individual docker containers
https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

Files are directly edited over an internal SMB share where Windows hosts connect to the Linux share. These are the hosts running PhpStorm.

The machine is exposed to the world using port 80. LAN has access to all ports.

I'm at a bit of a loss how to properly setup Xdebug using PhpStorm where only those within our LAN can trigger the debugger and debug from map files from a Linux host on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A [DBGp proxy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/multiuser-debugging-via-xdebug-proxies.html) would be the answer here.

1. It limits all debugging connections from the web server to a single host inside the LAN.
2. It allows you to perform multi-user debugging with the help of IDE keys.

JFYI, in Xdebug, it's the web server that initiates a TCP connection to the client (the DBGp proxy in this case), so some Docker networking magic is required here.